# how to navigate to specific screen when press the notification in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I'm using `react native push notification` with **firebase**. I'm getting notifications and everything is good, but the issue is **OnOpenNotfication** function is firing up two times.It's showing {} the first time and its calling itself automatically. When I press on the notfication then it also fires and showing nothing I mean in notify there is nothing.
But I want to call onOpenNotification only when I click on the notification.And I also want to navigate the user from onOpenNotfication to specific screen but it fires up automatically so that's why I can't
Here is the code.

```
 componentDidMount = async () => {
   
    fcmService.registerAppWithFCM();
    fcmService.register(onRegister, onNotification, onOpenNotification);
    localNotificationService.configure(onOpenNotification);

    function onRegister(token) {
      console.log('[App] onRegister: ', token);
    }

    function onNotification(notify) {
      console.log('[App] onNotification: ', notify);
      const options = {
        soundName: 'default',
        playSound: true, //,
        // largeIcon: 'ic_launcher', // add icon large for Android (Link: app/src/main/mipmap)
        // smallIcon: 'ic_launcher' // add icon small for Android (Link: app/src/main/mipmap)
      };
      localNotificationService.showNotification(
        0,
        notify.title,
        notify.body,
        notify,
        options,
      );
    }

    function onOpenNotification(notify) {
      console.log('[App] onOpenNotification: ', notify);
      alert('Open Notification: ' + notify.body);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you. You can try using this logic.

```
 import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
    
    componentDidMount(){
        firebase
            .notifications()
            .onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
              console.log('onNotificationOpened', notificationOpen);
              this.handleNotification(notificationOpen.notification, false);
            });
    }
    
    handleNotification(notification: Notification, appClosed){
       //notification will have your custom data and here you can apply your logics
       //you can use navigation here according to your logic.
       navigatorRef.navigate("routeName");
    }
```